# What is the use of WITH TIES keyword in SELECT statement in SQL Queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES EmpNumber,EmpName 
FROM Employee 
Order By EmpNumber DESC
```

This above query return more than five result, What is the use of "With Ties" keyword SQL Queries.

Comment: It's for returning records about `Employees` that don't prefer wearing cravats.

Comment: Another excellent example: [48412942](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412942) showing with ties and row_number()

Answer (score 89):

From [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

> Used when you want to return two or more rows that tie for last place
> in the limited results set.

Note the example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/055ec/2)

We have a table with 6 entires 1 to 4 and 5 twice.

Running

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES *
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY ID;
```

returns 6 rows, as the last row is tied (exists more than once.)

Where as

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY ID;
```

returns only 5 rows, as the last row (2 in this case) exists only once.

Comment: Thanks,Now I can see the difference. It mainly depends on the last row of the result set. If the last row is repeated then it will generate more rows. You made it more clear with the example.

Comment: Interesting, after 13 years of developing I'd never seen this and needed to find something like this today. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a similar keyword to discard the siblings if any ? In our case to return 4 rows.

Answer (score 26):

From [here](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-top/)

> Using **TOP WITH TIES** to include rows that match the values in the
>   last row

If you want to use **TOP WITH TIES** you must use **order by**.

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Price] [float] NULL) 
GO
```

The following illustrates the INSERT statement that inserts rows into an existing table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 1' , 258.2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 2' , 265.3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 3' , 267.8)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 4' , 268.9)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 5' , 267.9)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] VALUES ('Bicycle 6' , 267.9)
GO
```

then

```
SELECT TOP 4 WITH TIES
ProductName, Price
FROM Products
ORDER BY Price
```

In this example, the two expensive product has a list price of 267.9. Because the statement used **TOP WITH TIES**, it returned one more products whose list **prices** are the same as the forth one.

[image: here]

Comment: why this answer is not a top one, it's absolutely clear and simple!

Answer (score 16):

Check this query and will be more clear.

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES *
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY ID;
```

RESULT:-
1
2
3
4
5
5

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY ID;
```

RESULT:- 1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 2):

For easier understanding, let's explain with a simple example on [Northwind DB](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs/instnwnd.sql). Assuming you require products for the same price.

```
select 
     UnitPrice
    ,count(UnitPrice) as PriceCount
from Products
group by
    UnitPrice
order by 2 desc
```

[image: with ties-1]]

You are now aware that there are currently 4 products whose price is 10 for example., but you will still get 2 rows -as many results as you sent with `top` clause-.

```
select top 2 UnitPrice,* from Products where UnitPrice=10
```

[image: with-ties2]]

You have to submit the query with `with ties` clause for all matching rows. Even though you sent `top 2`, you will get more matching lines.

```
select top 2 with ties UnitPrice,* from Products where UnitPrice=10 order by 1
```

[image: with ties]]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

> Returns two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited
> results set. You must use this argument with the ORDER BY clause. WITH
> TIES might cause more rows to be returned than the value specified in
> expression. For example, if expression is set to 5 but two additional
> rows match the values of the ORDER BY columns in row 5, the result set
> will contain seven rows.
>
> You can specify the TOP clause with the WITH TIES argument only in
> SELECT statements, and only if you've also specified the ORDER BY
> clause. The returned order of tying records is arbitrary. ORDER BY
> doesn't affect this rule.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding of WITH TIES clause,
if you want to [duplicate values], which the column specified in the Order By.

Answer (score 1):

The `WITH TIES` allows you to return more rows with values that match the last row in the limited result set. Note that `WITH TIES` may cause more rows to be returned than you specify in the expression.

The selection of which the rows to return is **nondeterministic**. 
This means that if you run the query again, without the underlying data changing, theoretically you could get a different set of three rows. 
In practice, the row selection will depend on physical conditions like :

- optimization choices
- storage engine choices
- data layout
- etc...

If you actually run the query multiple times, as long as those physical conditions don’t change, there’s some likelihood you will keep getting the same results. But it is critical to understand the “physical data independence” principle from the relational model, and remember that at the logical level you do not have a guarantee for repeatable results. Without ordering specification, you should consider the order as being arbitrary, resulting in a nondeterministic row selection.

Your current result is like below :

```
EmpNumber EmpName  Ranking
11        Maria    1
23        José     2
456       Pedro    3
456       Pedro    3 --WITH TIES
```

Probably your table is containing duplicate rows or may have historical ones as in general the EmpNumber is unique.

From [Reference](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819)

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe in detail, How `TOP WITH TIES` works

Important Note: The clause `WITH TIES` can be used only `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, both clauses are required.

Let us understand how this clause works with a straightforward example:

Suppose I have 10 rows in the table and out of them 6 rows have the same value in a column which is used in `ORDER BY`, when I use the `TOP 5` rows, it will return me only 5 rows. But if I use `TOP 5 WITH TIES`, it will return all the rows that have the same value as the last record of the top 5 that I have, which means total records.

Hope the concept is clear to you.

Let us understand with a very simple example.

```
--Created a simple Table
DECLARE @tblStudent TABLE (
ID INT,
FName VARCHAR(50),
Marks INT
)
--Inserted some records in the table
INSERT INTO @tblStudent VALUES
(1,'Name1',50),
(2,'Name2',10),
(3,'Name3',10),
(4,'Name4',10),
(5,'Name5',10),
(6,'Name6',10),
(7,'Name7',70),
(8,'Name8',35),
(9,'Name9',45),
(10,'Name10',10)
```

The following query, with the keyword `TOP 5`, will bring me a resultset with 5 rows.

```
SELECT TOP 5  * FROM @tblStudent ORDER BY Marks;
```

[image: Result with 5 rows, all having the same Marks]

I'll run the same query and I'll have an additional keyword `TOP 5 WITH TIES`.

```
SELECT TOP 5 WITH TIES * FROM @tblStudent ORDER BY Marks;
```

[image: Result with 6 rows, all having the same Marks]

This time instead of returning only 5 rows, it will return all rows. This is because when we use `TOP WITH TIES` it returns all the rows that have the same value.

I hope this example makes it clear how TOP works and how its behavior changes when we use `TOP WITH TIES`.

SQL Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/w4QY6lm2

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we a have a table named myTable with below data:

### ID    NAME        SALARY

1    Geeks      10000

4    Finch      10000

2    RR         6000

3    David      16000

5    Lesley    7000

6    Watson     10000

**Query:**
SELECT * from myTable

order by salary desc

fetch first 3 rows only;

Output: 
We got only first 3 rows order by Salary in Descending Order

### ID    NAME    SALARY

3    David    16000

1    Geeks    10000

4    Finch    10000

**Note:** In the above result we got first 3 rows, ordered by Salary in Descending Order, but we have one more row with same salary i.e, the row with name Watson and Salary 10000, but it didn’t came up, because we restricted our output to first three rows only. But this is not optimal, because most of the time in live applications we will be required to display the tied rows also.

**Real Life Example** – Suppose we have 10 Racers running, and we have only 3 prizes i.e, first, second, third, but suppose, Racers 3 and 4 finished the race together in same time, so in this case we have a tie between 3 and 4 and that’s why both are holder of Position 3.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH TIES option is important to the TOP() predicate. It enables the last place to
include multiple rows if those rows have equal values in the columns used in the ORDER BY
clause.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49L1n.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UmuY.png)

As you see in the first image ,  the last row has more identical values in the db  .. then in the next picture  the with ties get all the rows identical with the same value in the column selected  in the "order by"

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * from myTable order by rank desc fetch first 3 rows With Ties;
```

gives

```
ID    NAME       Rank
--------------------------
3    Dhoni     1
1    Geeks     2
6    Watson    3     **// We get Tied Row also**
4    Finch     3
```

Comment: As I figured out this query involving `Fetch` and `With Ties` doesn't work in SQL Sever, It works in Oracle.