# How to find the first row which has value not equal to Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the first date where Ten_Yr_CAPE is not having 0 value.
Output table should have Country column and Date Column on which has Date when Ten_Yr_CAPE became greater than 0.

I wrote the below query but it pulling all records having 'Ten_Yr_CAPE' <> 0. I need only the initial date. Can anyone help me.

Select TOP(1) returns only one record. I need one record for each country. So totally 20 records for each country

```
    select  [Date],[Country] from [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table4$] where 
    [Ten_Yr_CAPE] <> 0 
     Group by [Country], [Date]
     Order by [Date] ASC
```

Comment: HINT: `SELECT TOP(1)  [Date],[Country]` Check [**manual**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql)

Comment: Select TOP(1) returns only one record. I need one record for each country. So totally 20 records for each country

Comment: I see, I tought you only need one. That is why is better provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: use `top 1 with ties` or `row_number()` then

Answer (score 5):

I think aggregation is the simplest method:

```
select  t.[Country], min(t.[Date])
from [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table4$] t
where [Ten_Yr_CAPE] <> 0 
Group by [Country]
Order by [Date] ASC
```

Comment: This appears to be the best answer, assuming it works as needed

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM (     
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [COUNTRY]
                                  ORDER BY [Date]) as rn
     FROM [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table4$] 
     WHERE [Ten_Yr_CAPE] <> 0 ) AS T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Comment: My answer work for cases where you need multiples fields for the same row, but in this case because you only need the date, is better just `group by` like @Gordon did.

Answer (score 3):

You can use top (1) with ties as below:

```
select top (1) with ties  [Date],[Country]
from [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table4$]
where [Ten_Yr_CAPE] <> 0 
order by row_number() over(partition by [Country] order by [Date] ASC)
```

Comment: This Works fine.. Thanks!!

Comment: This is by far the most confusing answer :p

Comment: @JoePhillips Actually is a very clever one. Is similar to my answer but remove the need to use a subquery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853725/what-is-the-use-of-with-ties-keyword-in-select-statement-in-sql-queries Interesting

Comment: @JoePhillips Yes you learn something every day. I knew this method, but isnt on the top of my mind because Im used to the `ROW_NUMBER()` subquery